# How many numbers below $n$ with a square number of distinct prime factors?

Tags: number-theory, functions, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Is there a nice closed-form expression for, or asymptotic formula for the number of numbers below $n$ with a square number of distinct prime factors?

**Motivation:**

As a student who studies mathematics in my spare time, I encountered some questions asking about the number of numbers below certain limits that adhere to certain elementary factor properties and later was thinking about it, when it occurred to me that there were many, seemingly simple or natural, questions to ask about "counting functions" that nothing I know can help with...

So, more generally, on top of an answer to the above, are there nice toolkits or pieces of machinery that can, with some property, tell me the number of numbers below $n$ with that property? (even if this toolkit only works for a specific subset of properties, I would be interested)

Comment: 1 is a square number, right? For now let's notate your function, which operates on positive real numbers, as $\chi_{\omega^2}(n)$ (someone will think of something better later). Then $\chi_{\omega^2}(n) > \pi(n)$, where $\pi(n)$ is the prime counting function. Since 1 has zero distinct prime factors and $0 = 0^2$, then $\chi_{\omega^2}(1) = 1$.

Comment: Have you looked in the OEIS? https://oeis.org/A065515 might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @RobertSoupe: Sorry for not replying till now. A065515 officially says that it is the number of prime powers below $n$, which seems quite different from $\chi_{\omega^2}(n)$...

Comment: That's what I thought and that could still be the case. But most of the time, when an OEIS search gives me a result that matches this much, it turns out to be the right result after all. Try to find the smallest $n$ for which the OEIS entry and your function differ.

Comment: @RobertSoupe: This is because under 210(=$2\times3\times5\times7$), all numbers which have a square number of factors are prime powers (i.e. have 1 prime factor). 210 is the smallest number with a square number of distinct primes factors that is not 1, and after it these two sequences cease to be equivalent.

Comment: You're right, then, A065515 is a false match. At this point you might have to give a bounty on this one, but you have so few points...

Comment: Thank you, @RobertSoupe, for putting the bounty up! I could have never done that with my reputation!

It's nice to occasionally find those who care actually care about your question...

Comment: No problem. I'm going to wait to until after Memorial Day to award; you're of course now free to accept an answer at any time but I'd suggest also holding off past the holiday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\pi_k(n)$ be the number of integers $\le n$ with exactly $k$ distinct prime factors.  You are looking for $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\pi_{m^2}(n)=\pi(n)+\pi_4(n)+\pi_9(n)+\ldots$.  Hardy and Ramanujan proved the upper bound $$
\pi_k(n) < c(n/\log n) \cdot (\log\log n + d)^{k-1}/(k-1)!$$ for some constants $c$ and $d$, and Erdös and Pillai (independently) proved the lower bound
$$
\pi_k(n) > c'(n/\log n) \cdot (\log\log n)^{k-1}/(k-1)!
$$
for some constant $c'$.  So, putting things together, you have
$$
\frac{c'(\log\log n)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}<\frac{\pi_{k}(n)}{n/\log n}<\frac{c(\log\log n+d)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}.
$$
Taking $g(z)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{m^2-1}}{(m^2-1)!}$, you have
$$
c'g(\log \log n)<\frac{\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\pi_{m^2}(n)}{n/\log n}<cg(\log\log n + d).
$$
*Update:*

After spending some time looking into the asymptotic growth of functions like $g(z)$, analytic with every derivative at the origin equalling zero or one... which seems interesting and may be worth its own question... I think that $g(z)$ is $\Theta(e^z / \sqrt{z})$ for large $z$.  If that's correct, then in fact
$$
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\pi_{m^2}(n)\in\Theta\left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{\log\log n}}\right).
$$

Comment: The last inequalities with constants $c'$ and $c$?

Comment: Also, summed over $k$.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it...

Comment: Your observation is intriguing! Being but a student, I am sorry to say, though, I do not understand what it means for a sum to be "inside" ($\in$) the value of some function... Could you explain? Is it an alternative form of asymptotic-equivalence notation?

Comment: You should be a bit careful with how you state the lower bound: for very large $k$ it certainly fails (the LHS is $0$)

Comment: @fedja With an error of $O(n/\log^A n)$ for some large positive $A$, we can begin with $k\le 4\log\log n$. This way, we know $k$ cannot be too large.

Comment: @i707107 Yes, of course. But that has to be spelled out though it doesn't influence the main argument.

Comment: @fedja Yes, I agree on your point that it has to be spelled out.

Comment: @IskyMathews: $\Theta(f(n))$ isn't a function, it's a set.  Specifically, it's the set of functions $g(n)$ such that $A < g(n) / f(n) < B$ for some positive constants $A$ and $B$ and for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: Ah yes, of course... Forgot about $\Theta$, $O$ etc. notation

Comment: I am accepting your answer, as it has been the most helpful, but I would like to see if you could ever justify or find out the reason behind your last asymptotic conjecture - it seems pleasingly simple!

Comment: Heuristically one might guess at the asymptotic $n/\sqrt{\log \log n}$ from the fact that $\omega(n)$ is "normally distributed" around $\log \log n$, and a "random integer" of the same size as $\log \log n$ is square with "probability" $\sqrt{\log \log n}$.

Comment: The conjecture turned out to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\omega(n)$ be the number of distinct prime factors of $n$. Distribution of the numbers satisfying $\omega(n)=k$ is well-known. The method is discussed in Montgomery & Vaughan 'Multiplicative Number Theory' volume 1, chapter 7, exercise 3. Denote by
$$
F(s,z)=\prod_p \left(1+\frac z{p^s-1}\right)\left(1-\frac1{p^s}\right)^z.
$$
The product is taken over prime numbers. This product converges for $\Re(s)=\sigma>1/2$, uniformly for $|z|\leq R<\infty$.

Let $\rho_k(x)$ be the number of $n\leq x$ for which $\omega(n)=k$. Then 
$$
\rho_k(x)=G\left(\frac{k-1}{\log\log x}\right)\frac{x(\log\log x)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!\log x}\left(1+O_R\left(\frac k{(\log\log x)^2}\right)\right)
$$
uniformly for $1\le k\le R\log\log x$. 
Here, $G(z)=F(1,z)/\Gamma(z+1)$, and $G(0)=G(1)=1$. Also, $G(z)\asymp 1$ on $0\leq z\leq R$.

It is okay to have $R=e+1$ since we have the number $B(x,R)$ for which $\omega(n)\geq R\log\log x$ is 
$$
B(x,R)=O\left( x(\log x)^{R-1-R\log R} \right)
$$
and $R-1-R\log R<-1$.

Then it remains summing over the ones with $k=l^2$. Let $y=\log\log x$.

First, note by Stirling's formula that 
$$
\frac{y^{l^2-1}}{(l^2-1)!} \sim \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi(l^2-1)}}\left( \frac{ey}{l^2-1}\right)^{l^2-1}\sim \frac1{l\sqrt{2\pi} }\left( \frac{ey}{l^2-1}\right)^{l^2-1}.
$$
Let $n=l^2-1$. We have
$$
\left( \frac{ey}{l^2-1}\right)^{l^2-1}=\exp\left(n\log\left(\frac{ey}n \right) \right)
=\exp\left( n \left(1+\log(\frac yn -1 +1) \right)\right).
$$
We sum over $\sqrt{1+0.6y}\leq l \leq \sqrt{1+Ry}$, so that $-1<\frac1R -1 \leq \frac yn-1\leq \frac1{0.6}-1<1$. Over $\frac1R-1\leq x\leq \frac1{0.6}-1$, we have 
$$
\log(1+x)\leq x - \frac16 x^2. 
$$
This gives
$$
\exp\left( n \left(1+\log(\frac yn -1 +1) \right)\right)\leq \exp\left(n(1+\frac yn -1 - \frac16 (\frac yn -1)^2)\right)
$$
$$
=e^y\exp\left(-\frac16 n(\frac yn -1)^2 \right)=e^y \exp\left(-\frac16 (\frac y{\sqrt n} - \sqrt n)^2 \right).
$$
Thus, 
$$
\sum_{\substack{{\sqrt{1+0.6y}\leq l \leq \sqrt{1+Ry}}\\{n=l^2-1}}}\exp\left(-\frac16 (\frac y{\sqrt n} - \sqrt n)^2 \right)\asymp 1. \ \ \ \ (*)
$$
Then 
$$
\sum_{\sqrt{1+0.6y}\leq l \leq \sqrt{1+Ry}} \frac1{l\sqrt{2\pi} }\left( \frac{ey}{l^2-1}\right)^{l^2-1}\asymp \frac{e^y}{\sqrt y}.
$$
Hence
$$
\sum_{\sqrt{1+0.6y}\leq l \leq \sqrt{1+Ry}} \frac{y^{l^2-1}}{(l^2-1)!} \asymp \frac{e^y}{\sqrt y}.$$

We sum over the remaining $l$ with $\asymp \log y$ intervals of the type $[\sqrt{1+\alpha^{t+1} y},\sqrt{1+\alpha^t y}]$ with $0<\alpha<1$ and varying $t$.

By the same method above, we have
$$\sum_{\sqrt{1+\alpha^{t+1}y}\leq l \leq \sqrt{1+\alpha^t y}}\frac{y^{l^2-1}}{(l^2-1)!}\ll \frac{e^{\alpha^t y}}{\sqrt{\alpha^t y}}\left(\frac1{\alpha^t}\right)^{\alpha^t y}\ll \exp\left((\alpha - \alpha\log \alpha)y\right).
$$
Since $0<\alpha - \alpha\log \alpha <1$, the sum over whole remaining range contribute to
$$
\ll (\log y)\exp\left((\alpha - \alpha\log \alpha)y\right) \ll \frac{e^y}{\sqrt y}.
$$
Therefore, by combining all estimates, we have
$$
\sum_{l\leq \sqrt{1+Ry}} \frac{y^{l^2-1}}{(l^2-1)!}\asymp \frac{e^y}{\sqrt y}.
$$
This proves that the conjectured answer by @mjqxxxx is true.

Comment: What does $\asymp$ mean? Sorry if I am amateur at this.

Comment: $f(x)\asymp g(x)$ means that there are positive constants $c$ and $C$ such that $c f(x) \leq g(x) \leq Cf(x)$.

Comment: Ahhh -- much clearer. Thank you :) ..... well, by much clearer, I mean I can read it, but I don't entirely know what any of it means. Looks pretty, though :))